# how to resize image

Tags: c#, image, resize

I am a little forgetful
have made it many times and can not find the code from the last time I made it
how do I get it to resize more than one picture

i do like this

```
Guid imageName;
imageName = Guid.NewGuid();
string storePath = Server.MapPath("~") + "/MultipleUpload";
if (!Directory.Exists(storePath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(storePath);
hif.PostedFile.SaveAs(storePath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(hif.PostedFile.FileName));

string tempPath = "Gallery";
string imgPath = "Galleryt";
string savePath = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, tempPath);
string TempImagesPath = Path.Combine(savePath, imageName + hif.PostedFile.FileName);
string imgSavePath = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, imgPath);
string ProductImageNormal = Path.Combine(imgSavePath, "t__" + imageName + hif.PostedFile.FileName);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(hif.PostedFile.FileName);
switch (extension.ToLower())
    {
        case ".png": goto case "Upload";
        case ".gif": goto case "Upload";
        case ".jpg": goto case "Upload";
        case "Upload": hif.PostedFile.SaveAs(TempImagesPath);
            ImageTools.GenerateThumbnail(TempImagesPath, ProductImageNormal, 250, 350, true, "heigh");
            Label1.Text = "";
            break;
    }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the 'e' tag?

Comment: i have tryed set this in. and I think it's something like       
 ImageTools.GenerateThumbnail(TempImagesPath, TempImagesPath, 250, 350, true, "heigh"); 
but dident work

Comment: Andrew is talking about http://weblogs.asp.net/arturtrosin/archive/2009/01/26/separation-of-concern-vs-single-responsibility-principle-soc-vs-srp.aspx
Will help to clean up your code, as the resizing issue has nothing to do with the uploading process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself
but thanks anyway for looking

but now I have another problem
I will not keep the original file on the page it should be deleted again when it is finished resize
If I just delete it right after in the code with

```
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Gallery/" + imageName + hif.PostedFile.FileName));
```

so it says that it can not delete the file because it is being used by another process.

```
                        string storePath = Server.MapPath("~") + "/MultipleUpload";
                        if (!Directory.Exists(storePath))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(storePath);

                        string tempPath = "Galleryt";
                        string imgPath = "Gallery";
                        string savePath = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, tempPath);
                        string imgSavePath = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, imgPath);
                        string imgSavePath2 = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, imgPath);
                        string ProductImageNormal = Path.Combine(imgSavePath, imageName + hif.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string ProductImagetemp = Path.Combine(savePath, "t__" + imageName + hif.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string ProductImagetemp2 = Path.Combine(imgSavePath2, "b__" + imageName + hif.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(hif.PostedFile.FileName);

                        switch (extension.ToLower())
                        {
                            case ".png": goto case "Upload";
                            case ".gif": goto case "Upload";
                            case ".jpg": goto case "Upload";
                            case "Upload": hif.PostedFile.SaveAs(ProductImageNormal);
                                ImageTools.GenerateThumbnail(ProductImageNormal, ProductImagetemp, 600, 600, true, "heigh");
                                ImageTools.GenerateThumbnail(ProductImageNormal, ProductImagetemp2, 250, 350, true, "heigh");

                                Label1.Text = "";
                                break;
                            default:
                                Label1.Text = "Status: Denne filtype er ikke tilladt";
                                return;

                        }
```